# How can I create a partition that can't be mounted from an OS on another partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, security

For security reasons I want to use two operating systems on two different partitions. I want to prevent the partition of the 'secure' OS to be mounted by another OS. 
- by default the secure OS is visible on the non-secure system.
- I can make it non visible in the non-secure OS by using the 'disks' tool (which changes fstab I presume) but this can be reversed.
- I could encrypt the secure OS but I have only the choise between encrypting the home folder (not secure enough) and the entire disk (not just the partition).

- is there a solution to make the secure partition unmountable?

Comment: The non-secure OS users shouldn't have the privileges to mount.

Comment: @guillermo chamorro: I agree... But I am looking for a solution which is independed of the non-secure OS.

Comment: You can encrypt just a partition and not the entire drive.  However, the partition that you encrypt you will lose all data on.  See: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-encrypt-a-single-partition-in-linux/